# Bonds are traded and settled at clean price or Dirty price?

Tags: fixed-income, bond, pricing, trade

Are Bonds are traded and settled at clean price or Dirty price ?

Answer (score 0):

They are typically *quoted* as a "clean" price for comparability. When they *trade* (and settle) then the buyer must pay any accrued interest to the seller, which makes up the "dirty" price.